# Python: List containing tuple and integer

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list that is a combination of a tuple and integer

ex: K = [(7,8),8]

How do I access the first element of the tuple, 7?

I tried K[0[0]] and was not successful.

Comment: Get the first element from list like this `K[0]` and then get the first element of the tuple like this `K[0][0]`

Answer (score 4):

Try doing the following:

```
    >>> k = [(7,8),8]
    >>> k[0]
    (7, 8)
    >>> k[0][0]
    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing element like this in a collection is wrong -
    K[0[0]]

In this case, you are indexing the 0th element of 0 itself, which definitely causes an error. Try doing k[0][0]